# How to create custom animation in angular material dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am using angular material dialog component code and want to add slide right animation on open/close duration.

```
openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: check animated.css for this. You can add remove class name to do css effect easily

Comment: Any suggestions ? I'm in the same issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-dialog-animation-1a7cc5) put this in index.hml

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" />
```

call this in  component

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog,{panelClass: ['animate__animated','animate__slideInLeft']});
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue fully. Clicking on the backdrop will not execute the animation. Only time this solution works is if the dialog is explicitly closed by clicking on the close icon.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the library called **ng-dialog-animation** and use the service provided by this called **NgDialogAnimationService**, to open the dialog instead of the MatDialog.

Your component would have the following line of codes:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog } from "@angular/material/dialog";

 import { NgDialogAnimationService } from "ng-dialog-animation";

@Component({
selector: "dialog-content-example",
templateUrl: "dialog-content-example.html",
styleUrls: ["dialog-content-example.css"],
 })

export class DialogContentExample {
constructor(public dialog: NgDialogAnimationService){}

openDialog() {
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogContentExampleDialog, {
  width: "250px",
  // option1 
  animation:{to:"aside"},})

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
});
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mina Shah

I tried but its not working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-mat-dialog-animation